# powershell get-winevent how to get only path and exe file?

Tags: powershell

How to get from applocker winevent only path of file and name of file (file.exe), i mean how to filter this info

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL"
```

Comment: Question asked again here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879084/powershell-get-winevent-applocker-get-only-path#comment109447849_61879084

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the below, to see if this helps your use case. I too, don't have this on a system I can test at this point.

```
<#
Pull all AppLocker logs from the live AppLocker event log 
(requires Applocker)
#>

Get-WinEvent -logname "Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL"

<#
Search for live AppLocker EXE/MSI block events: "(EXE) was prevented 
from running":
#>

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    logname = 'MicrosoftWindows-Applocker/EXE and DLL'
    id      = 8004
}

<# 
Search for live AppLocker EXE/MSI audit events: "(EXE) was allowed 
to run but would have been prevented from running if the AppLocker 
the policy was enforced":
#>
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    logname = 'MicrosoftWindows-Applocker/EXE and DLL'
    id      = 8003
}
```

> [Get-AppLockerEvent - Get event details related to AppLocker
>   activity](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-AppLockerEvent-Get-deecb85e)
>
> AppLocker events include a number of helpful details that are buried
>   within the event object or XML.  This function will extract helpful
>   information like the username, rule name, file path, file hash, and
>   file signature details for easy viewing.
>
> [Download: Get-AppLockerEvent.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-AppLockerEvent-Get-deecb85e/file/122204/1/Get-AppLockerEvent.ps1)

Answer (score 0):

That log is empty on my machine, but maybe you can do something with the xml from the event:

```
[xml]$xml = get-winevent application | select -first 1 |
  foreach { $_.toxml() }

$xml.event

xmlns                                                 System EventData
-----                                                 ------ ---------
http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event System EventData
```

Oh I see, you have to restart the appidsvc after setting the group policy.  You can use the filepath or fullfilepath properties:

```
$a = get-winevent "microsoft-windows-applocker/exe and dll" |
  select -first 1
[xml]$xml = $a.toxml()
$xml.event.userdata.RuleAndFileData

xmlns              : http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemas/event/Microsoft.Windows/1.0.0.0
PolicyNameLength   : 3
PolicyName         : EXE
RuleId             : {fd686d83-a829-4351-8ff4-27c7de5755d2}
RuleNameLength     : 24
RuleName           : (Default Rule) All files
RuleSddlLength     : 53
RuleSddl           : D:(XA;;FX;;;S-1-5-32-544;(APPID://PATH Contains "*"))
TargetUser         : S-1-5-21-1528843147-373324174-1919417754-1001
TargetProcessId    : 3876
FilePathLength     : 51
FilePath           : %PROGRAMFILES%\GOOGLE\CHROME\APPLICATION\CHROME.EXE
FileHashLength     : 0
FileHash           :
FqbnLength         : 1
Fqbn               : -
TargetLogonId      : 0x4d253a0
FullFilePathLength : 59
FullFilePath       : C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```