# powershell Get-WinEvent applocker get only path

Tags: powershell

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL" | Select-Object Message -Unique
```

and i got

> %SYSTEM32%\CMD.EXE was allowed to run.  %PROGRAMFILES%\INTERNET
>   EXPLORER\IEXPLORE.EXE was prevented from running.

how to get only path? nothing after exe?

Comment: How do you enable logging anyway?  You asked the question twice?

Comment: i didnt, it just appears in event viewer, yes i asked twice i think now i asked the question correctly

Comment: But you even got answers to your other question. Why don't continue there?